# less file1 file2 | cat -- why does it work?

Tags: pipe, cat, less

When I uss `less file1 file2` I get both files shown in the "less buffer viewer", but `less file1 file2 | cat` prints the content of both files appended to stdout. How does less know if it should show the "less buffer viewer" or produce output to stdout for a next command? What mechanism is used for doing this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`less` prints text to stdout. stdout goes

- to a **terminal** (/dev/tty?) and opens the default buffer viewer
- through a **pipe** when piping it to another programm using |  (`less text | cut -d: -f1`)
- to a **file** when redirecting it with > (`less text > tmp`)

There is a C function called "isa*tty*" which checks if the output is going to a tty (less 4.81, main.c, line 112). If so, it uses the buffer viewer otherwise it behaves like `cat`.

In bash you can use test (see `man test`)

- -t   FD  file descriptor FD is opened on a terminal
- -p   FILE exists and is a named pipe

Example:

```
[[ -t 1 ]] && \
    echo 'STDOUT is attached to TTY'

[[ -p /dev/stdout ]] && \
    echo 'STDOUT is attached to a pipe'

[[ ! -t 1 && ! -p /dev/stdout ]] && \
    echo 'STDOUT is attached to a redirection'
```

Comment: @tfh If STDOUT is not attached to a pipe or a redirection, it's correct that they don't print that STDOUT is attached to a pipe or a redirection. Put all three in a script. Call `bash script.sh`, `bash script.sh | cat`, `bash script.sh > file`, and see what output you get.

Comment: `stdout` isn't something that can be "written to a file".  It's something you `write()` *to*.  `less` doesn't have to do anything differently depending on whether its output is a file, pipe, socket, or block device, or whatever.  It only matters that it's not a tty, so it just behaves like `cat`.  (I assume you knew this and just chose the wrong words to explain it, but I thought I'd point this out for other readers).

Comment: So you mean it is the task of less to behave like cat in my specific question - or more general: behave like the next command in a pipeline. From what I understood I can not assume that the exact same behaviour is implemented in a different tool also.

Comment: @tfh: No, `less` doesn't "figure out" that `cat` is next.  It just behaves like `cat` regardless of what it next, if it's stdout is not a tty.

Comment: @MichaelD.: thanks, corrected my answer.  I just guessed that `less` would go ahead and use one TCGETS to get the terminal dimensions or discover that it's not a tty, but apparently I guessed wrong.

Comment: "print stdout to a file" makes no sense either.  `stdout` is a destination, a file descriptor, or the file that the file descriptor is open on/to (e.g. a device file like a tty, or a regular file if redirected to a file).  `sys.stdout.write` means to do a `write` *to* stdout.  Notice how there's no filename or pipe involved: that happens before, when stdout is redirected (and that happens before `less` is even `execve()`ed.)

Answer (score 7):

`less` checks if its `stdout` is a terminal, and behaves like `cat` when it isn't (copies stdin to stdout until EOF).

This feature lets you write scripts or programs that always send their output (e.g. `--help` output) through `less` while still allowing easy redirection to a file.  It would suck if `some_command --fullhelp > help.txt` still waited for space-bar on stdin to page through the text, or something.  Some commands (e.g. `man`) check that their own output to decide whether to send their output through a pager or not.  If you run `man ls > ls.txt`, it never invokes your `$PAGER`.

`less`'s cat-like behaviour is handy if you forget to edit it out of a one-liner when adding more stages to a pipeline, too.

---

`less` needs to figure out the terminal dimensions (screen size, to know how many lines to show at once).   The [`ioctl(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) it uses on `stdout` would return ENOTTY on a non-terminal, so it can't avoid handling the non-terminal case anyway.  `less` actually uses [`isatty(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) before checking the terminal dimensions, but `isatty` works by trying a tty-only ioctl and checking for lack of error.

Even a simple pager like `more(1)` (at least the util-linux version) has this feature, because it's probably the simplest sane behaviour to implement for that case.

---

Note that when you pipe something *into* `less` (e.g. `grep foo bar.txt | less`), it does have to open `/dev/tty` for keyboard input.  (You can see it do this with `echo foo | strace less`).